# working of ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I've got multiple objects stored in a file .This is regarding the ObjectInputStream. If I've got the below code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

Object obj1 = (Object)ois.readObject();

ois.close();
 ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

Object obj2 = (Object)ois.readObject();
```

My question is : will the readObject called from the second Object stream (obj2) be the 1st or 2nd object in the file

Comment: Wouldn't `ois.close();` also close `fis`? If so, the second read might just fail.

Comment: What if I don't close the stream ie. don't use ois.close(). Also, if I close fis.close() will is close both the ObjectInputStream

Answer (score 3):

It will infact throw an exception. Calling close on the ObjectInputStream will close the FileInputStream as well.

Comment: What if I don't close the stream ie. don't use ois.close(). Also, if I close fis.close() will is close both the ObjectInputStream

Comment: @Tarun It won't work; ObjectInputStream does buffering internally.  You either need to keep using the same ObjectInputStream, or you need to start over with a fresh FileInputStream.

Comment: @Tarun - Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like you want to be able to retain the read position in your input streams, in case of a crash or other unexpected file stream close. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you stored the objects. If you used one single ObjectOutputStream, then you better also use one single ObjectInputStream.

If you used separate streams for the output, you also should use separate streams for the input. But this is not really recommended.

---

For your "persistent queue", I would recommend something like this:

On the sending side:

- Create a ByteArrayOutputStream, wrap an ObjectOutputStream around it.
- Write the object to the OOS, and close the OOS.
- Get the `byte[]`, and write it together with a header indicating the length to your queue-stream.

On the receiving side:

- read a header length from the queue stream.
- read a `byte[]` of the given length from the queue stream.
- create an ByteArrayInputStream from this array, and wrap an ObjectInputStream around it.
- read one object from the OIS, close the OIS.

When you store parts of your queue, make sure to always store whole messages (i.e. the header together with the object).

Of course, it might be easier to use already existing solutions, like JMS (where you would create an ObjectMessage, and submit it to the queue).

Comment: basically, i'm trying to create a persistent queue.

Comment: @Tarun: For a persistent queue, you probably want to use separate ObjectOutputStreams. I just edited the answer for a probable solution.